# AngularJS - Jquery Slider loading

Tags: jquery, slider, angularjs

I'm trying to use a jquery plugin within a partial in angularjs.

**Directive:**

```
app.directive('slideit',function() {
    return function(scope, elm, attrs) {
        elm.bxSlider({
          adaptiveHeight: true,
          mode: 'fade'
        });
    };
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="sliderwrapper" >
    <ul class="slider" slideit>
        <li ng-repeat="image in dealer.images"><img ng-src="{{image}}" alt="" /></li> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

The output shows me, that the bxSlider() is successfully running on the directive. But the list and/or the  tags are not touched. Just with normal AngularJS code but not with the jQuery plugin.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issues is with the timing. "slideit" directive is invoked before your list is rendered, and afterwards it's totally redrawn again by ngRepeat and bxSlider doesn't even suspect that this is happening.

Just to validate this hypothesis (don't use this in production, as it's very ugly and might not even work if your model changes) try:

```
app.directive('slideit',function() {
    return function(scope, elm, attrs) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            elm.bxSlider({
              adaptiveHeight: true,
              mode: 'fade'
            });
        }, 100);
    };
});
```

There's a bigger issue here: you're trying to "compile" HTML with both Angular an JQuery and they are not necessarily compatible. To avoid the clashes, I'd recommend rendering the list by hand inside your directive and then calling bxSlider on that dynamically constructed DOM. It's not pretty, but it should be more stable. Ex:

```
<ul slideit="dealer.images"></ul>
```

directive:

```
app.directive('slideit',function() {
    return function(scope, elm, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(attrs.slideit, function(images) {
            var html = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                 html += '<li><img ng-src="' + images[i] + '" alt="" /></li>';
            }
            elm[0].innerHTML = html;
            elm.bxSlider({
              adaptiveHeight: true,
              mode: 'fade'
            });
        });
    };
});
```

(I haven't tested this, it's just an idea)

Comment: Make sure to check images.length is greater than 0.

Answer (score 1):

This works. It has an `ng-repeat` within the directive. The `bxSlider` gets started on `ready()` of the element.

```
app.directive('slideit',function() {
    return {
       restrict: 'A',
       replace: true,
       scope: {
         slideit: '=' 
       },
       template: '<ul class="bxslider">' +
                   '<li ng-repeat="slide in slides">' +
                     '<img ng-src="{{slide.src}}" alt="" />' +
                   '</li>' +
                  '</ul>',
       link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
          elm.ready(function() {
            scope.$apply(function() {
                scope.slides = scope.slideit;
            });                    
            elm.bxSlider({
              adaptiveHeight: true,
              mode: 'fade'});   
            });
       }
    }; 
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div slideit="images"></div>
```

**Edit:** Here is a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/cNQp3L).

Comment: Checked it, hasn't workd. An } was missing but even without the error the tags weren't "bxSlider"'ed. Just an additional span tag was there... strange.

Comment: Added a plnkr in the answer. Images are shown, but too many bullets still.

Comment: Fixed it. Solution is using a elm.ready(), in which you assign the images (slides) and kickoff bxslider. See plnkr.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:
Add the following directives:

```
app.directive("mySlider", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: true,
        template: '<ul class="slider"><li check-last ng-repeat="image in dealer.images"><img ng-src="{{image}}" alt="" /></li></ul>'
    };
});
app.directive('checkLast', function () {
        return function (scope, element, attrs) {
            //console.log(scope.$position);
            if (scope.$last=== true) {
                element.ready(function () {
                    $('.slider').bxSlider({
                      mode: 'fade',
                      pager: false
                    });    
                })
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

just maintain the dependency of file js file!

```
 <script src="/yii-application/frontend/web/js/libraries/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="/yii-application/frontend/web/js/libraries/angular/angular-ui.js"></script>
 <script src="/yii-application/frontend/web/js/recordata/country.js"></script>
 <script src="/yii-application/frontend/web/js/libraries/jquery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/yii-application/frontend/web/js/libraries/flex/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/yii-application/frontend/web/assets/e3dc96ac/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/yii-application/frontend/web/js/libraries/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/yii-application/frontend/web/js/searchResult.js"></script>
  <script src="/yii-application/frontend/web/js/Flight.js"></script>
```

like below!!!!